# ContentType on ascx returns error

Tags: asp.net, contenttype

When I'm trying to use `ContentType` on `*.aspx` page, it is working fine.

```
Response.ContentType = ContentType;
```

But when I'm trying to use on `*.ascx`, following error occurred:

> The name 'ContentType' does not exist in the current context

how I should resolve this issue ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting it like this (say we're setting text/plain):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your error and select `Resolve` option. There might be many namespaces that contains this type but select one that you used in `aspx`.